# Is there a way to write a nested query in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I an new to mongoDB and I am trying to achieve below SQL query equivalent in mongoDB

SELECT ROUND((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFODOCS WHERE ML_PRIORITY = HIGH AND PROCESSOR_ID = userid)
/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFODOCS WHERE PROCESSOR_ID = userid) * 100)
AS EFFORTS FROM DUMMY;

EFFORTS = Total High Priority Infodocs / Total Infodocs for a given Processor

I tried to write an aggregation pipeline using $match, $group, $count but the issue is once I get an output for one subquery i did not find anyway how can i compute another subquery and finally use the outputs of both subquery to determine the final result.

Comment: Can you add examples of the data you are working with in MongoDB? It would be rather hard to properly respond based on the SQL query alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mongo-y way would not to execute two different queries to get the 2 different counts, but to do a sum it dynamically with one query.

You can achieve this in many different ways, here is an example how to use [$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#:%7E:text=Example-,Definition,%7D%20%7D) while `$group`ing to do a conditional sum.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      PROCESSOR_ID: "1"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalCount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      priorityHighCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$ML_PRIORITY",
                "HIGH"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      EFFORTS: {
        $round: {
          "$multiply": [
            {
              $divide: [
                "$priorityHighCount",
                "$totalCount"
              ]
            },
            100
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```